Are there weaknesses other than existential forgery to using Fiat-Shamir type signatures without a hash?
I am a college professor interested in using post-quantum cryptosystems like Dilithium in my linear algebra classes.  The mathematics is not a problem, but these are mostly not computer science students so I am wondering if I could avoid talking about hash functions.  In particular, I'm wondering what would happen if instead of properly hashing the message together with the other information, one just XORed it.  Dilithium is based on the Fiat-Shamir transform, so I know that not using a proper hash makes it vulnerable to existential forgeries.  Are there other weaknesses?  We already teach many public-key systems in basic classes in forms that are vulnerable to existential forgery (e.g. RSA), so if that's the only vulnerability I'm not too concerned.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

This paper (roughly) investigated your question, and showed that one could replace the random oracle with a "simple" hash functions. While these don't include XORing, they do include

Linear functions $\bmod p$, and
mapping $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ to its digit decomposition $\vec x\in\mathbb{Z}_2^{\lceil \log_2 p\rceil}$

I imagine either could be used for CS undergrads without too much difficulty.

Excellent!  That looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks, @Mark!
